# Colar Projecto Django en virtualenv

Tags: python, django, debian, virtualenv

Hola a todos tengo la siguiente situación.

Cree mi aplicación Django en un entorno virtualenv, la aplicación ya corre es perfecta en mi maquina virtual, todo el proyecto fue creado dentro de un entorno virtualenv.

Se me presenta la siguiente situación necesito trasladar mi proyecto al servidor final, el cual tiene la mismas características de mi maquina virtual, me gustaría saber cuales son las pasos para lograr clonar mi proyecto del entorno virtualenv para trasladarlo a la nueva maquina.

O que pasos se me recomienda para que mi proyecto corra en el servidor final ya que al copiar y pegar se me están presentado muchos errores por las librerías que use para su desarrollo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿No puedes crear un `virtualenv` en la máquina de producción? En tu máquina local puedes hacer un `pip freeze` para que te saque la lista de bibliotecas que usas y con eso crear un `requirements.txt` que puedes llevar a tu entorno virtual en producción. Allí haces `pip install -r requirements.txt` y ya tienes exactamente las mismas bibliotecas.

Comment: En el título: "Colar" ¿es esa la palabra que querías usar?

Comment: Lo primero que debes utilizar es una herramienta de gestión de versiones, como `git`, que con ayuda de `.gitignore`, va a permitir que se "copien" sólo los archivos que realmente son de desarrollo, y no archivos locales de configuración o de sistema. Y también, por supuesto, utilizar `pip freeze` dentro de tu `virtualenv` local, como indica el compañero abulafia, para instalar en el servidor final las librerías mismas que estás utilizando en tu virtualenv local.

Answer (score 0):

Copias los requerimientos de tu local

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

luego que tienes los requerimientos, los instalas en el servidor

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```